# The REST-way to GET resources which contain user related flags (favorited, liked, voted ...)

Tags: api, rest

Currently I am developing an App and within that App I want the signed in user to retrieve resources, and I also want to show the user that if he/she used to like or favorite each resource. But I don't know how to design the API in the REST-way.

e.g., for stackoverflow itself, there are answers under each question, the endpoint maybe:

> /questions/:qid/answers

If I upvote an answer, I will always see an orange up arrow on the answer, but you won't.

If we both call the same endpoint, the API must response different contents according to user who authorizes this request. Then this API is not **stateless**.

*How to design the API in the REST-way?*

Comment: Is stream an actual resource or is it just a noun?

Comment: just a noun. it could be replace with `hottest`, `newest`, etc. represent photos lists for different orders and/or filters.

Comment: Nouns as url segments is not restful. You should consider applying filters like hot or new with a query parameter like `/photos?filter=hot`

Comment: @TimCastelijns you miss the point. My point is, e.g., for stackoverflow itself, there are answers under each question, the endpoint maybe `/questions/:qid/answers`. If I upvote an answer, I will always see an orange  up arrow on the answer, but you won't. But we both call the same endpoint.

Comment: I know, I'm not trying to provide an answer for your question. Just a general tip for using restful apis; don't use nouns as url segments

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the requests into two APIs:

- GET /photos/stream
  to get list of photos
- GET /photos/id?user_id=
  to get the info of the photo
  identified by    the id and relevant info of the photo with the user.

The drawback is you need to issue many requests, one for each photo. This keeps the interface clean but not performance-wise good solution.

Or you can add a parameter to GET /photos/stream as

GET /photos/stream?user_id=

This returns the photos together with info for each user.

Comment: Look how `plus.google.com` does: in OP's case it would be `/photos/stream/{userid}`, possibly `/{userid}` being optional for anonymous access

Answer (score 0):

GET /photos/stream

to list all photos, if a registered user calls this API, redirect it to below one.

GET /photos/stream/userid

to list photos for userid, along with other behaviors binded with this user.